# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner in python. I'm not able to understand what the problem is?

```
def list_benefits():

        s1 = "More organized code"
        s2 = "More readable code"
        s3 = "Easier code reuse"
        s4 = "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"
        return s1,s2,s3,s4

def build_sentence():

        obj=list_benefits()
        print obj.s1 + " is a benefit of functions!"
        print obj.s2 + " is a benefit of functions!"
        print obj.s3 + " is a benefit of functions!"

print build_sentence()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   Line 15, in <module>
   print build_sentence()
   Line 11, in build_sentence
   print obj.s1 + " is a benefit of functions!"
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 's1'
```

Comment: no its perfectly fine..it just calls the function & that function does the rest

Comment: That doesn't relate to the code you have posted here. Something else must be the problem

Comment: thats the whole code...check the link if u wish...
[link](http://codepad.org/yQXHzIbE)

Comment: Since you  have called the `build_sentence()` function using the `print ` statement, and since the function returns nothing, the `None`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You return four variables s1,s2,s3,s4 and receive them using a single variable `obj`. This is what is called a `tuple`, `obj` is associated with 4 values, the values of `s1,s2,s3,s4`. So, use index as you use in a list to get the value you want, in order.

```
obj=list_benefits()
print obj[0] + " is a benefit of functions!"
print obj[1] + " is a benefit of functions!"
print obj[2] + " is a benefit of functions!"
print obj[3] + " is a benefit of functions!"
```

Answer (score 11):

You're returning a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). Index it.

```
obj=list_benefits()
print obj[0] + " is a benefit of functions!"
print obj[1] + " is a benefit of functions!"
print obj[2] + " is a benefit of functions!"
```

Answer (score 8):

```
class list_benefits(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s1 = "More organized code"
        self.s2 = "More readable code"
        self.s3 = "Easier code reuse"

def build_sentence():
        obj=list_benefits()
        print obj.s1 + " is a benefit of functions!"
        print obj.s2 + " is a benefit of functions!"
        print obj.s3 + " is a benefit of functions!"

print build_sentence()
```

I know it is late answer, maybe some other folk can benefit
If you still want to call by "attributes", you could use class with default constructor, and create an instance of the class as mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 5):

Variables names are only locally meaningful.

Once you hit

`return s1,s2,s3,s4`

at the end of the method, Python constructs a tuple with the values of s1, s2, s3 and s4 as its four members at index 0, 1, 2 and 3 - NOT a dictionary of variable names to values, NOT an object with variable names and their values, etc.

If you want the variable names to be meaningful after you hit `return` in the method, you must create an object or dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in python flask: I had the same problem... There was a "," after I declared my my form variables; I am working with wtforms. That is what caused all the confusion

Comment: It seems that you are showing the solution for different code.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning four values from a function and storing them in a variable **obj**, it does not mean *obj* is an object. So you can't access the values as *obj.s1, obj.s2*... instead, use obj[index] to access values.

```
print(obj[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

When multiple values are returned from a function as comma-separated, they will be returned as a tuple. So *obj* here will be a tuple with values (s1, s2, s3, s4).

```
>>>print(type())
<class 'tuple'>

>>>print(obj[0]) # will print value of s1
"More organized code"
```