# what is wrong with the tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, tuples

I am trying to make a shootRect appear halfway up playerRect and one pixel in front. In the code I try to have shootRect drawn

My code:

```
MESH = ((playerRect.x + 1), (playerRect.x + 1), ((playerRect.topleft.y + playerRect.bottomleft.y) / 3), ((playerRect.topleft.y + playerRect.bottomleft.y) / 2))
shootRect = (screen, WHITE, MESH)
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == ord(' '):
pygame.draw.shootRect
```

The error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\***\***\***.py", line 76, in <module>
    MESH = ((playerRect.x + 1), (playerRect.x + 1), ((playerRect.topleft.y + playerRect.bottomleft.y) / 3), ((playerRect.topleft.y + playerRect.bottomleft.y) / 2))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: Try printing `playerRect.topleft` and see what happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290114/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`playerRect.topleft` is a tuple of the format `(x, y)`. Instead of `playerRect.topleft.y` to get the `y` value, you want `playerRect.topleft[1]`:

```
MESH = ((playerRect.x + 1), (playerRect.x + 1), ((playerRect.topleft[1] + playerRect.bottomleft[1]) / 3), ((playerRect.topleft[1] + playerRect.bottomleft[1]) / 2))
shootRect = (screen, WHITE, MESH)
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == ord(' '):
pygame.draw.shootRect
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of `playerRect.topleft.y` and `playerRect.bottomleft.y` you can use `playerRect.left`. It is the same value.

So in place of

```
playerRect.topleft.y + playerRect.bottomleft.y
```

you should have

```
playerRect.top + playerRect.bottom
```

**BTW:** if you need `halfway ... playerRect` than you have `playerRect.centery` or `playerRect.centerx` or both `playerRect.center`

Comment: I am using the midpoint formula so now sense I looked over it, it should have been `(((playerRect.topleft[1] + playerRect.bottomleft[1]) / 2) + 10), (((playerRect.topleft[1] + playerRect.bottomleft[1]) / 2)) - 10)` to have top 10 pixels above and below making it 20 pixles thick.

Comment: I corrected my answer - in place of `.topleft[1]` you can use `.top`, and in place of `.bottomleft[1]` you can use `.bottom`. But finally you can do the same with `playerRect.centery+10,playerRect.centery-10`